# Calibrating a system with matrices

Tags: calibration

I have several monochromatic LEDs that are coupled with controlers (PWM), thermometers and light sensors (spectrometer).

For each LED:

- The controlers allow me to change the voltage/current applied to the LEDs, which, in turn, modulate the light's intensity (I call the value `Input`)
- The thermometers measure the `Temperature` of the source
- The spectrometer measures the actual light intensity at several wavelengths (typically 101 points between 400 and 700 nanometers), it measures the 'Spectral power distribution' (`SPD`) of the LED.

My objective is to build a robust representation of the LED behavior. I need this because I observed that the SPD variation is non-linear: it varies with the `Input` but also with `Temperature`, and the greater the `Input` the greater the `Temperature`.
The heatsink is an active cooling system so I can modulate the temperature and see the result in terms of `Output`

What typically happens is that the LED color (and `SPD`) will change when the `Temperature` changes: for the same `Input`, if the `Temperature` is low, the LED will have a greater overall `Output` and its peak emission wavelength will be shorter (say 590 nanometers). When `Temperature` rises the overall `Output` will be smaller and the peak wavelength will be longer (for example 605 nanometers).

In practice, this means that a yellow LED will behave like a Red LED at higher temperatures. If I have a robust representation of this behavior, I can get a better prediction of my LED 'Output' and adjust my cooling system to get the color that I want.

_

For simplicity, I have restrained my analysis of the `SPD` to only one wavelength in the following example. The idea behind this approach is that if I have a model of the system's behavior for each wavelength that depends on the same variables `Input` and `Temperature`, I will be able to represent my LED in every possible practical situation:

`Output` corresponds to the value of one of the 101 channels of the spectrometer, 'Temperature' is an indicator of the LED temperature measured on the heatsink, 'Input' is the PWM control value applied to the LED, that varies between 1% and 100%.

There is a quite clear relationship between the 3 variables and I am searching for a function:

```
Output(Input, Temperature)
```

[image]

It seems quite clear that a 2nd degree polynomial function fits well with the relationship between Input and Output at a given Temperature:

[image]

And another 2nd degree polynomial can fit the varying parameters of the first function, in relation to Temperature:

[image]

How would you proceed to build a representation of such a system? Since I have hundreds of such `Output` datapoints associated with `Wavelength`, `Input` and `Temperature`, I thought that it would be useful to use matrices to represent the system with non-linear polynomials?

Comment: I'm having trouble at understanding what is your question. Are you looking of a way to obtain the parameters of the 2nd order fit for more temperatures, written in a matrix form?

Comment: Yes, although I really appreciate @Jeffrey's answers, I have no clear idea how to write his equations in matrix form (sorry but I am not trained as an engineer...) I think that I can guess the logic of how to solve my problem but I don't know how to use matrices... :(

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix form"? Do you simply mean in a spreadsheet format as you are showing above? What do you mean by "100 systems like this"? Do you mean that you have 100 sensors and you want to calibrate each of them? Do you mean that you have 100 sets of data tables as you show and you want to create a way to automatically analyze the values?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer yes that's what I mean, my tables are much larger and I have automated systems to create them, and indeed I have several hundreds of such systems. I believe that I can use linear algebra techniques to represent my system by I don't know where to start

Comment: This system is not easily amenable to linear algebra analysis, indeed it may not be at all ... I have to consider further. In the meantime, the robust approach is to do a non-linear regression fitting across the parameters Input and Temperature to Output using the functional forms I now posted in my revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have two independent control parameters, the input and the temperature. You have a choice on where you decide to set the dependencies. Suppose we define $I$ for input, $T$ for temperature, and $O$ for output. You might decide to make each term in your polynomial a function of temperature.

$$O = A(T)I^2 + B(T)I + C(T)$$

Alternatively, you might decide to represent the functional form as a separation of variables.

$$O = \left(AI^2 + BI + C\right)f(T)$$

When you have a first principles reason to choose one or the other equation, do so. Alternatively, you may want/need only to do an engineering empirical approach. The simplest expression to handle is the separation of variables with $f(T) = T$ (temperature is a linear multiplier over all other parameters). Your plots show that this approach will likely not work robustly. The second plot suggests that the first two terms are non-linear and the third term (constant $C$) is linear in temperature.

$$A(T) = a_1T^2 + a_2T + a_3$$
$$B(T) = b_1T^2 + b_2T + b_3$$
$$C(T) = c_2T + c_3$$

The full analytical expression that combines all expressions above is not amenable to an easy analysis, especially also when it is to be done over hundreds of values. The full analytical expression is also not easily amenable to a linear algebra decomposition (if at all). The approach that you show to obtain quadratic analytical expressions using just a small subset table is a reasonable start.

The next step would do non-linear regression fitting to an entire set of data using the combined functions. The objective would be to obtain fitting constants and their regression uncertainties, for example $a_1 \pm \Delta a_1$, $b_1 \pm \Delta b_1$, $\ldots$. This is an advanced level of work that is not within the domain of typical spreadsheet applications. Search for software to perform multi-parameter non-linear regression fitting to review options.

Finally, when you have the non-linear regression values, you can apply them in the linear propagation expression for relative uncertainty in output $\left(\Delta O/O\right)^2$ following from the basic theme [previously mentioned](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43413/calibrate-a-sensor-using-another-already-calibrated-sensor) (although such an approach may be exhaustive).

Comment: one suggestion that would help me follow, is that assuming that Temperature has $n$ levels and Intensity has $m$ levels, would be to state the dimensions of each matrix. E.g. matrix O is [nxm]  (or what have you) and A matrix is  [nx1].  (To be honest I am still confused on what the OP wants to accomplish, so I can't really envisage the output).

Comment: @JeffeyJWeimer thanks for your additional suggestions. Indeed the example in my post was created using a spreadsheet program. However I can use Python/Numpy to get the work done, I just used the spreadsheet and less datapoints in order to illustrate the principle of my problem in a simpler way.

Comment: @NMech sorry if my question is confusing. The physical setup is a monochromatic LED on a heatsink, coupled with a spectrometer. The output value varies depending on the voltage/current that feeds the LED, and on the temperature of the LED. The LED peak wavelength will vary with the temperature (the light may be yellow at low temp and red at higher temp for ex.) I said that I have 100 systems but it's not exactly true: I have 100 measurements of the same LED at different wavelengths. My example represents what happens for one channel of the spectrometer. Maybe I should reformulate my question?

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com no need to apologize. I am just trying to understand what exactly you mean by "calibration". Are you after the best fit for the different A, B and C for each temperature? In essence, are  you looking for a best fit of the coefficients of best fit?

Comment: @NMech I have updated my question, hopefully the objective that I am trying to reach is more clear now.

Comment: @NMech Yes my idea is that if I have the best fit of the coefficients of best fit for each wavelength of my LED, then I may have a robust representation of my LED output in spectral terms with only two variables 'Input' and 'Temperature'. My hypothesis was that it may be possible to use matrix algebra to represent the system of equations

Comment: My closing note remains as this: The objective is best realized using a tool that is designed for multi-parameter, non-linear regression fitting.